# Is mutating "copy" of initial state inside a passed reducer function in "Redux Toolkits" createSlice() a bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

## Context

I'm trying to create the state for a multi-level accordion menu, where the top-level items are called subjects, each subject has multiple chapters and each chapter will have multiple articles.

At any given time only a single "Subject" can be in the "selected" state. The same applies to chapters and articles, with the additional restriction being they need to be "Children" of a parent in the "selected" state.

## Code

I have a deeply nested object that is to be passed as the initial state to the `createSlice()` method,it has the following shape,

```
const initialState = {
  currentArticle: null,
  currentChapter: null,
  currentSubject: null
  subjects: [
    {
     id:"001",
     chapters: [
        {
         id: "001001",
         articles: [
          {
           id: "001001001",
           selected: false
          },
          //....... more articles
         ],
         selected: false
       },
       //....... more chapters
     ],
     selected: false
    },
    //....... more subjects
  ]
}
```

Following is my `createSlice()` method,

```
export const articleNavigationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "articlenav",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setTopic: (state, { payload }) => {
      const newNavigationState = initialState.subjects.map((subject) => {
        if (payload.id === subject.id) {
          subject.selected = true;
          state.currentSubject = subject.id
        } 
        return subject;
      });
      state.subjects = newNavigationState;
    },
    // ...... more reducer functions
  },
});
```

The `subjects` array is directly used for rendering the UI, Every time a dispatch function is called I conditionally use the initial state and then calculate the next state,(**those conditions are not included in the following code snippets for simplicities sake**), **For now let's consider that I use the initial states "subject" array every single time I need to calculate the next state instead of using the previous state passed to the reducer.**

The reason for using the initial state is to not have to manually set the selected state of nested objects to false, in case the parents `selected` state changes.

## Problem

However when I dispatch an action that executes the "setTopic" reducer function I get the following error,

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of object '#<Object>'

## Attempts to solve the issue

1. Using the spread operator to create a new copy of `initialState` within the reducer.

```
const copyInitialState = { ...initialState }
const newNavigationState =  copyInitialState.subjects.map((subject) => {
//............
```

2. Using Object.assign() to create a new Object, within the reducer

```
const copyInitialState = {};
Object.assign(copyInitialState, initialState);
const newNavigationState = copyInitialState.subjects.map((subject) => {
//............
```

3. create 2 copies of the initial state, before invoking `createSlice` and pass one copy inside the `createSlice()` invocation as the initial state and use the other copy within the passed reducer function.

```
const initialStateCopy = Object.assign(initialState);
const initializedInitialState = Object.assign(initialState);

export const articleNavigationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "articlenav",
  initialState: initializedInitialState,
  reducers: {
    setTopic: (state, { payload }) => {
      const newNavigationState = initialStateCopy.subjects.map((subject) => {
//............
```

I.E : I tried this approach with the spread operator as well.

## The only solution that works(not a desirable approach )

explicitly declare a completely new constant and initialize it in the exact same way as the `initialState` object. In this case, this simply means I'm copying the exact same object creation code one after the other so that they are completely two different objects,

```
const initialState = {//.... deeply nested object}
const initialStateExplicitCopy = {//.... deeply nested object}

export const articleNavigationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "articlenav",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setTopic: (state, { payload }) => {
      const newNavigationState = initialStateExplicitCopy.subjects.map((subject) => {
```

## Question

I think this has to do something with Immer and how it treats the initial state Object. I see that even though I do an `Object.assign()` nested objects are sealed and frozen.

Does this mean I'm attempting to perform something wrong? or something which is considered bad practice? Does this in any way make the reducer impure? If so I don't see why because the initial state never changes, I'm just using the initial state all the time to calculate the next state.

Is there a  better approach to handle this while using the redux toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the problem is the attempt to mutate `initialState`, for a couple different reasons.

**It's only safe to write code that "mutates" data if that data has actually been passed through Immer and wrapped in proxies, so that Immer can track the attempted changes**.  When you reference `initialState`, that object hasn't been handed to Immer yet, so your code really is *trying* to mutate `initialState`.

Fortunately, when you call `createSlice({initialState: someInitialStateValue})`, `createSlice` internally "freezes" that value to make sure you don't accidentally mutate it for real later on.  That's why you're getting the error - it's telling you you *are* doing something wrong.

Conceptually, I'm not sure *why* you're trying to always base the calculations off of `initialState`.  Wouldn't you want to be doing updates based on the *current* state as the starting point?

If you truly do need to use `initialState` as the starting point, the best option is to use Immer directly and feed it `initialState`.  Immer's main function is exported from RTK as `createNextState`, so you can use that to wrap your current logic

```js
import { createNextState } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const articleNavigationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "articlenav",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setTopic: (state, { payload }) => {
      const newNavigationState = createNextState(initialState.subjects, draftSubjects) => {
        const subject = draftSubjects.find(subject => subject.id === payload.id);
        if (subject) {
          subject.selected = true;
          state.currentSubject = subject.id
        }
      }
      state.subjects = newNavigationState;
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Right, I too realize my current approach is a bit clunky, I've decided to refactor it to base the next state off of the current one.